# GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT when trying to attach texture

Tags: opengl-es

I get an error `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT` after I try to create a framebuffer that renders to a texture. I can't figure out what is wrong, any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: Fixed it! Working code:

```
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 768, 1024, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rboID);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rboID);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, 768, 1024);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);

    glGenFramebuffers(1, &backFramebuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, backFramebuffer);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rboID);
    [self checkFramebufferStatus];
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

Note: If your version doesn't work, make sure you check for errors after each and every call AND that you clear the error before your first call, else you'll be error-checking the code before that.

Comment: I was comparing my code to this snippet to try and find an error.  For Android OpenGL ES 2.0 the catch for me was GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT vs GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16.  In the glRenderBufferStorage make sure the depth component is GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16.  Tough one to catch as every line of code was identical otherwise to your snippet.

Comment: You should also leave the bad code, so people reading it after the fact can see the solution. Or atleast explain what you checked. Regardless, thanks for showing the fixed code.

Comment: @Halsafar Yes, that's a pretty common error. Good thing you noted it. However, if you wrapped checked for errors, you'd catch this error a lot quicker, hence my last comment "check for error after every call".

Comment: Sorry I appreciate this may be a minor point but I see your code doesn't include _OES / OES anywhere. With my headers, I have to use GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES instead of GL_FRAMEBUFFER ... and so forth.
I was just wondering if you actually removed the '_OES' for presentation? (and thanks by the way, this sample code DID help).

Comment: @tea in ES2, these calls aren't extensions, thus no OES ;-)

Comment: @Halsafar: Why is this causing an error at all? What's exactly wrong with GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT?

Comment: @Nick please don't remove the invalid code from the question, as it makes the question you asked mostly useless for future visitors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is likely that the texture is incomplete.  The default MIN_FILTER for a texture specifies mipmapping, but you've provided only for Texture Level 0, so the texture itself is incomplete.

Add calls to glTexParamter to set the MIN_FILTER to one of the non-mipmapped modes.

Comment: I added calls to create a non-mipmapped texture, but this results in the same error. Still thanks though, learning along the way.

Comment: It was an incomplete texture! Not because of the mipmaps, but because of some other stuff. Working code is in the question text. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I had two confusing errors in my case: [1] I was trying to use a GL_LUMINANCE texture as the target (magically not allowed, for some reason), and [2] I did not glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0) before glFramebufferTexture2D(...)

Comment: indeed it doesn't allow GL_LUMINANCE or GL_ALPHA as the pixel type, this was the problem in my code.

Comment: "glTexParamter to set the MIN_FILTER" can you give an example?